# How to populate a ListBox with SendMessage?

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox, sendmessage

I am trying to populate a ListBox with data I am reading from a text file, but have had no luck.  I tried several ways to do `SendMessage` (please see below) but get the same "invalid cast type" error.

ListBox:

```
CreateWindow("listbox", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL|
                         LBS_NOTIFY, 20, 90, 200, 365,
                         hwnd, (HMENU)LST_LISTBOX, NULL, NULL);
```

I keep on changing the `SendMessage`:

```
SendMessage(LST_LISTBOX, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)10); //myline[i]);

SendMessage(LST_LISTBOX, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) myline[i]);

SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd, LST_LISTBOX), LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) myline[i] );
```

What would be the best way to populate a listbox from a file?

Comment: What is `myline`?

Comment: Myline is an input line from a text file.

Comment: My question is really what is `myline` declared as?  I know what your intent is of `myline`, but you need to state exactly what `myline` is in terms of variable type.

Comment: If `myline` is `std::string` for instance, then you would use `(LPARAM) myline.c_str()`

Comment: You may use the [ListBox_AddString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-listbox_addstring) macro to avoid the casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the message to the `HWND` that `CreateWindow()` creates. You can get that from the return value of `CreateWindow()`, or from `GetDlgItem()` after `CreateWindow()` is finished.

The `LPARAM` for `LB_ADDSTRING` and `LB_INSERTSTRING` needs to be a pointer to the 1st character of a null-terminated C-style string, eg:

```
char myline[size];
//fill myline as needed...

HWND hwndLB = CreateWindowA(WC_LISTBOXA, ... hwnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(LST_LISTBOX), ...);

// or:
// CreateWindowA(...);
// HWND hwndLB = GetDlgItem(hwnd, LST_LISTBOX);

SendMessage(hwndLB, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(myline));
```

Alternatively:

```
std::string myline;
//fill myline as needed...

HWND hwndLB = ...;

SendMessage(hwndLB, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(myline.c_str()));
```

---

**UPDATE**: based on comments you posted, `myline` seems to be a `std::string[20]` array, so you need to index into the array and call `c_str()` on the desired element, eg:

```
SendMessage(hwndLB, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(myline[i].c_str()));
```

Comment: Remy - Thank you for your suggestions.  WHen I try the alternative approach i get the follow error: 
C:\Users\Ronnie\Cpp\Paper.cpp|85|error: request for member 'c_str' in 'myline', which is of non-class type 'std::__cxx11::string [20] {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> [20]}'|
C:\Users\Ronnie\Cpp\Paper.cpp|147|error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\Ronnie\Cpp\Paper.cpp|69|note:   crosses initialization of 'HWND__* hwndLB'|

and I am not certain why.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: `string[20]` is an **array** of 20 strings. You need to use a **single** string with this API, as shown in my example. Also, the other error is likely because you are declaring local variables inside of a `case` statement without scoping them inside a `{ }` block, eg: `case SomeValue: { HWND hwndLB = ...; ... break; }`